# How do I make it so that my iPhone plays all audio through it's speakers by default?

Tags: bluetooth, settings, speakers

I recently bought an Amazon smart watch and I really love it. I can make calls and receive notifications through it, so it's always connected to my phone by default. The problem I'm having with it, is that my iPhone always uses it as the default audio source. Playing music, watching Youtube videos, Siri navigation, always chooses this watch as the audio source. I have to go in and manually change it every single time I need to listen to anything at all. Even when I change it, it doesn't stay changed, I have to manually tell it to use it's own speakers about 5 times a day.

There must be some way I can get this $1500 device (iPhone 12 Pro max, if that information is useful at all) that I would like it to assume I want to hear the audio from the thing I'm holding in my hand, the thing I pressed play on. It's impossible for me to believe that there is no way to fix this issue and that if I want to keep using this watch, I need to go in and manually change this setting every time I unlock the phone. Honestly, how can this be?

Thanks for reading. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try changing your watch to a different device type. Go into *Settings → Bluetooth* then tap on the “i” icon.  Select something like other.  Does that solve the issue?

Comment: unfortunately it did not. I changed the device type, and restarted. At first, it selected internal speakers as audio source, but then after putting it down for about 5 minutes and picking it up again, it had set itself back to the watch.

Comment: It’s a bit of a workaround, but try creating a shortcut (single line) that sets the *playback destination” to your iPhone/iPad.  Just tap it and it will set it for you.

Comment: Oh my gosh, you're a lifesaver. I've now set it up so that when I double tap the back of my phone, it automatically runs the shortcut. Brilliant. Thank you.

Comment: Go ahead and write up an answer and I’ll up vote you.  I’m just glad you got a solution that worked!

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a fix within the settings, but there is a workaround. Create a single line Shortcut that sets the audio playback destination to iPhone speakers, so you don't have to manually change it yourself every time you unlock your phone. To make it even more effortless, you can go to Settings > Accessibility > Touch > Back Tap, and set it up so that the shortcut executes when you simply tap the back of your phone twice.

Comment: Awesome!  Glad it worked out for you!